# How does Google use cross-domain iframes for recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, recaptcha, same-origin-policy

When using Google's recaptcha, it injects an iframe into the page, this iframe has a source of "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe...."

[image: google iframe]

However, when I try to use an iframe from a different domain I get a DOMException that the cross domain frame was blocked.

[image: my iframe]

Does anybody know how Google get around this?

Comment: They have whitelisted urls in server where it is used

Comment: The iframe originates from http://localhost:8888 and I am attempting to render it on http://localhost:8080. How do I replicate this whitelisting?